# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, scrollview

I'm very new to Android Application Development. I know my problem might be simple one. but, I'm sure it is related to layout.

Here's my issue: There's is a *listView* in the *Fragment*. When I click the button the new Fragment is added to the **ScrollView** in the main Layout. When I start the activity one fragment is already added to the activity. So, when I change the rotation the application does not crash.

But, new Fragment is added in the ScrollView after clicking button. But *this time* when I **change** the Rotation of the device the Application crashes giving following the error in the end. Can you help me solve this problem. Error occurs only when I change rotaion otherwise app runs fine.

Layout(XML) File activity_another_custom_list_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_another_custom_list_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewActivity"
android:background="@drawable/border">


<Button
    android:text="@string/add_fragments"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:onClick="addfrag"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/button">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">



<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewFragment"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment Layout another_custom_listview_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fraglistview"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java File AnotherCustomListViewActivity.java

```
package com.practices.app.practices;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;

public class AnotherCustomListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_another_custom_list_view);


}

public void addfrag(View v){
    AnotherCustomListViewFragment f = new AnotherCustomListViewFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.fragment,f);
    ft.commit();
}
}
```

Fragment Java Class AnotherCustomListViewFragment

```
package com.practices.app.practices;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class AnotherCustomListViewFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.another_custom_listview_fragment, container, false);

    String[] str = {"a","b","c","d"};
    ListView fraglist = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.fraglistview);
    ListAdapter listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
    fraglist.setAdapter(listadapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

Here's the full Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.practices.app.practices/com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3994)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5318)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:717)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                  at com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewActivity.onCreate(AnotherCustomListViewActivity.java:15)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6024)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3994) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5318) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:717) 
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewFragment did not create a view.
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2145)
                  at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5373)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:77)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                  at com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewActivity.onCreate(AnotherCustomListViewActivity.java:15) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6024) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3994) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1337) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5318) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:922) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:717)
```

I added reply to the answers in comment section but no one is answering.

Comment: This is unrelated to your problem, but you really do not need a `ListView` inside of a `ScrollView` and I would expect it to cause problems for you later (nested scrolling views which scroll on the same access are troublesome).

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.practices.app.practices.AnotherCustomListViewFragment did not create a view.` -- I find this particularly strange. Can you add some logging and make sure that `onCreateView()` is always returning something non-null?

Comment: `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` of your `fragment` in `activity_another_custom_list_view.xml` file needs to be `match_parent`

Comment: Adding ListView inside of ScrollView gives me this error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView. And onCreateView() does not return null. I've checked that. But it has problem setting content view (setContentView()) in AnotherCustomListViewActivity.java. Exception: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class fragment. Which is Fragment tag in activity_another_custom_list_view.xml file.

Comment: I have one Question, Does Fragment gets added to LinearLayout in activity_another_custom_list_view.xml? If not how do I add fragment specific to LinearLayout?

Comment: Import this: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` instead of `import android.app.Fragment;
` .

Comment: Using import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; package does not help.

Comment: Can you guys please check my Implementation whether it is right way to add fragment to Layout or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well i had this kind of problem few days back but after changing the drawable in my layout it solved my problem because my drawable was too large that's why it's causing the problem.
You can check in your layout for drawable if it is large than change it with other small one.
I think this will end your problem.

Comment: Well, I'm not using any Drawable in Fragment or ListView. Therefore, I don't think so it is problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, updating the libraries worked for me.